# How do you write and test your regular expressions?

Tags: php, regex, testing, wizard

Is their any wizards or tools to create and test regular expressions for PHP, because it is so difficult :( ?
thanks :)

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/514834/easy-to-use-regex-creator-tool

Answer (score 10):

[RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com/) is a widely popular app for this purpose. It also costs $40 and only runs on Windows.

For powerful free alternatives, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32290/1269037).

Comment: RegexBuddy is so good, I can't express it in 300 characters.  Paid back whatever ($30 or $50) I paid for it within days.

Answer (score 6):

[reAnimator](http://osteele.com/tools/reanimator/) is a nice tool to visualize your regex as a state machine- I find it useful sometimes.

Python also allows you to [view a regex parse tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101268/hidden-features-of-python/143636#143636), which can be helpful if you learn to read it.

Answer (score 6):

Unit testing with example data. Create two arrays, one with matching data, and one with non-matching data if necessary to test edge cases.

Comment: Whilst I like manually driven tools, like RegExpBuddy, and an add-in that's available for IntelliJ, having some unit tests to increase the long-term chances of the expression remaining valid is always a good idea.

Answer (score 4):

There are powerful [online tools](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32290/1269037). Offline,

- [The Regex Coach](http://weitz.de/regex-coach/) is a great free offline regex tool that I use fairly regularly.
- I like [RegEx Buddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com/) also, but it costs $40 and I'm cheap.

Answer (score 4):

Trial and <del>error</del> success.

Because I've spent the time to actually learn it, instead of relying on something else to do it for me.

Same applies to any language/tool - take a bit of time to learn the syntax and general ethos, and you'll be *far* more productive than relying on intellisense, code hinting, and so on.

Comment: Hear, hear!  (And the regex language isn't nearly as complex as it seems at first glance...  I get them right on the first try much more often than not.)

Comment: I get them right by the third try much more often than not, but I'll get back to you in a few years.

Answer (score 3):

[Expresso](http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm) is free Windows program and gives nice breakup and explanation of the regex under analysis.

For online tools that you can run right away from a browser, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32290/1269037).

Answer (score 2):

i always use this: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Comment: That was a terrible tool, based on Flash. Fortunately it's dead now.

Answer (score 1):

Trial and error.

And `print_r`.

Comment: That sounds like a most painful way to build Regexes.

Answer (score 1):

I really like [RegexPal](http://regexpal.com/), which is simple, clear, requires no installation and freely available online.

Comment: [Regex101](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32290/1269037) is much more powerful than RegexPal.

Answer (score 1):

Online... there's an ajax regex checker with js/pcre/posix implementations, that checks as you type.. way cool.

http://www.rexv.org

Answer (score 1):

Regex Buddy is overkill ($40) and works only on Windows. It was a good choice back in 2009 maybe.

Now we have free powerful online tools to build and test regular expressions. [Regex101](http://regex101.com/) is one of them:

- lets you select the RE engine (PCRE, JavaScript, Python)
- colorizes the matches
- explains the regexp on the fly
- has a debugger
- can create permalinks to the regexp playground.

More regexp testing tools in [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32290/1269037).

Answer (score 0):

I generally use [Rubular](http://rubular.com) when I'm working on testing a regular expression. You could also try [txt2re.com](http://txt2re.com/), it can be handy for helping you figure out an expression and can even generate relevant PHP code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another online regular expression tester for Java:

http://www.fileformat.info/tool/regex.htm

Answer (score 0):

I used to use The Regex Coach.  But because it's Perl based and most of the time I'm testing .NET regular expressions, I now use this [online .NET regular expression tester](http://regexhero.net/).

Answer (score 0):

I liked the emacs re-builder.

Answer (score 0):

I've written my own tool: [Regular Expression Tester](http://chris.photobooks.com/regex/default.htm).  Unlike many other web-based tools, this one can break a regex down into tokens and describe what each token is doing.  It's great for examining new expressions, or expressions that you wrote a long time ago and don't quite remember.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're talking about PHP, you may be interested in [Codebench](http://www.geertdedeckere.be/article/introducing-codebench). It is a tool, not specifically to break down regexes (you've got a lot of those listed already), but to benchmark them. Since it is rather generic, you can also compare non-regex solutions as often native string functions are faster. Moreover, it allows you to benchmark against multiple subjects (targets) as well. Hope you find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using unit-testing. That way, I can grow my regex incrementally, being certain that the first cases I tested still pass. And if ever I have to modify it, I have all my tests to back me up.

Answer (score 0):

For online test Regx http://www.regexr.com/ use this site and if your regx work on this then you can check it for php on writecodeonline.com with preg_match() function.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a python library to accomplish this, it is under [cloudtb.re](https://github.com/cloudformdesign/cloudtb/blob/master/cloudtb/re.py)

```
text = 'so foo is the opposite of bar but without foo there is no bar?'
exp = '(foo).*?(bar)'
searched = cre.research(exp, text)
print(searched)
```

[image: pprinted regular expression]