# How to abstract regexp by text patterns from a group of strings similar to each other?

Tags: regex

I have a group of strings looks like this:

```
/20110318/n279865419.shtml
/users/huanglr/168811561.html
/20110317/n279870252.shtml
/users/johnlee/442820392.html
/20110309/n279735352.shtml
/users/sambouet/049589392.html
/20110121/n279002750.shtml
```

The literal of each string could be varied.

I want the regexp `/\/\d{8}\/n\d{9}\.shtml$/` and `/\/users\/\w+\/\d{8,10}\.html$/` to be recognized from them.

Are there any libs or tools that are able to do this?

Comment: `$ man 3 regex`—not perl compatible but you can still match what you are after. BTW you have missed a `\d` after the `n` in your first regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [txt2re](http://txt2re.com/). It takes some minutes to see how it works but it's really worth the time.

Some other tools that help you to build regular expressions are in the answers to the question [easy to use Regex creator tool?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/514834/easy-to-use-regex-creator-tool).

Comment: Although `txt2re` is not able to resolve my problem immediately, it's very cool and inspirational. Thanks @Dennis.

Answer (score 0):

Is `find -regex ...` an option? http://www.linuxmanpages.com/man1/find.1.php

Comment: I don't think so. In my question the regexp is not exist before strings are parsed. The `find -regex ...` could not help.