# regex expression logic

Tags: regex

Regex expressions seems cocumbersome, they always drive me mad when trying to build it up. And i end up asking for help. But once i am given the result it looks really coool. Gurus, is there a way to go about it to break it up.

Comment: in case of regex i hope skill came for head banging :(

Comment: Two questions here: 1) Why is regex syntax so ugly?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/264309 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/484575 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/263072 and 2) How can I learn them?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/465119 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/616292 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/365362 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1558955 so either way, a multiple duplicate.

Comment: oh thx for those links. its all over the site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yuo can start with tutorials at [Regular-Expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) which provide a good starting point. The reference there is also invaluable as are the explanations how the regex engine works behind the scenes.

Actually, the fundamentals aren't that hard to grasp and once you got them it's not too hard. However, reading complex regular expressions is more like an arcane art; it can get pretty unwieldy quickly.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what you mean by "break it up", but here are a couple regex tutorials:

[The absolute bare minimum every programmer should know about regular expressions](http://immike.net/blog/2007/04/06/the-absolute-bare-minimum-every-programmer-should-know-about-regular-expressions)

[Extreme regex foo: what you need to know to become a regular expression pro](http://immike.net/blog/2007/06/21/extreme-regex-foo-what-you-need-to-know-to-become-a-regular-expression-pro/)

[Regulator](http://osherove.com/tools) is good, free tool that helps you to write regular expressions.

Comment: wow i never knew that there were tools for this!!!

Comment: That is why we are here, to share knowledge :)

Answer (score 2):

Doing web dev I have to do validation a lot.  I usually have http://www.regexpal.com/ open in a tab somewhere.  That site, combined with a tutorial, combined with a specific problem to solve is how I learned.

Answer (score 1):

Learning regular expressions requires you to start thinking a bit differently. The syntax is not important, what's crucial is learning that a regex is a way to describe a pattern. Of course you have to consider that you're explaining it to someone (a machine) which is by itself quite dumb, so you have to be very thorough and not assume anything.

Example: you don't look for a word, you look for a sequence of characters which you know can be in a word. You know it, but the machine doesn't, so you have to be specific (well, there are shortcuts, but that's not the point).

So learn to think character-wise instead of the abstract concepts familiar in natural language, and above all practice a lot.

I won't add links as they are already mentioned in other answers. Good luck, regexp are fun!

Comment: The shortcuts too pls. Just one or 2 maybe i can figure out the reset. :P

Comment: Well, the shortcut mention was only related to the "character belonging to a word" which is usually the `\w` special char, no dark magic to get things done sorry :)

Answer (score 1):

Learn to think like the machine by reading [How Regexes Work](http://perl.plover.com/Regex/article.html) by Mark Dominus. For more, go with [*Mastering Regular Expressions*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1565922573) by Jeffrey Friedl.

Answer (score 1):

Several of the answers already posted provide very good RegEx resource material.
However, one of the most important things to keep in mind before attempting
to become the master of RegEx is that **RegEx
is not appropriate for all types of matching problem**.

For example, most HTML cannot be
parsed in a general sense using RegEx. I see tons of questions on SO where
people are driving themselves nuts trying to apply RegEx in inappropriate
situations - it drives me nuts to see it!

My advise is to first get a grasp of where RegEx is appropriate to use and where
it is not. This alone will save you hours (days) of frustration.

The limitations of RegEx are those of using a finite state machine without
a stack. The big thing to realize is that RegEx does not
use a push-down stack to "remember" things it has come across. This
is not a problem as long as the pattern matching process only needs to know
where it is going next based on what it has matched so far and what it
"sees" as incoming text. This strategy is adequate for matching very complex
strings. However, it is not suited for situations where the matching process
needs to:

- skip over chunks of input delimited by nested delimiters (as in XML, HTML and most
  programming language grammars)

  Matching some number of "things" to the same number of the same "things"
  when the "things" are separated by some other stuff. In otherwords, don't
  try to count the number of occurances of some pattern, skip some stuff, and
  then match a prior pattern. Sometimes it can be done - but expect a rough ride!

In other words, if you need to think recursively about matching anything, 
**don't go there with RegEx**. Recursion requires memory and RegEx does not remember very well!

Some implementations of RegEx have been augmented to deal with some limited
types of recusions
but you will have to get to "know" your version of RegEx to find out what
the specific limitations (extentions) are.

Answer (score 0):

This tool might help : http://www.gskinner.com/RegExr/

Answer (score 0):

I could not completely understand your question but if you are looking for good and easier tutorial to get a tight fist on the regex then [phpro.org has a great tutorial about it](http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-Regex.html).

Comment: i mean any hard and fast rule to come about building it up. Or some thumb rule to analyse and build it up.

Answer (score 0):

This is my favorite reg ex site [regexlib](http://www.regexlib.com/RETester.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend [Expresso](http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm). Registration is needed after 30 days but it's completely free. It comes with a regex library and includes the author's [30 minute regex tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/regextutorial.aspx).

RegexBuddy is another popular tool but it's not free. You can view some [demos here](http://www.regexbuddy.com/demo.html).

I suggest you go through the tutorial and other helpful sites mentioned so far. Start off with simple patterns and understand them, then move on from there. It's tricky at first, and you need to understand what to look for to design a pattern that matches it.

[@gbacon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2177103/regex-expression-logic/2177444#2177444) mentioned the most popular book so I won't mention it again. A recent one that has good reviews is the [Regular Expressions Cookbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596520689).